# How to compile a Jasper jrxml file containing a reference to a webservice data adapter with Jasper library

Tags: jasper-reports

One of my clients has creating a report in Jasper Studio. In the report he has used a webservice datasource which comes with a corresponding data adapter. He uses this datasource to query a RESTful API. The jrxml file is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6581b4b3-5a83-4a40-b2a1-091d3e949e06">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapter.xml"/>
    <queryString language="WebServiceQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
  "getparameters" : { },
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "commercialCode",
    "expression" : "commercialCode"
  }, {
    "name" : "classification",
    "expression" : "classification"
  } ],
  "options" : {
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "rootPath" : "_embedded.airportList",
    "baseUrl" : ""
  },
  "headersMap" : { },
  "queryData" : "",
  "GETParameters" : { }
}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="commercialCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="classification" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="55" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="62" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="fed44789-e146-4b33-9f10-2f88eec34e8b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{commercialCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The report displayed above references also a data adapter, which is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<webServiceDataAdapter class="com.jaspersoft.webservice.data.WebServiceDataAdapterImpl">
<name>Airports</name>
<wsUri>http://localhost:8080/api/airports</wsUri><authType>none</authType><verb>get</verb><language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">json</language></webServiceDataAdapter>
```

I am not sure how I can compile this report using the Jasper report *library*. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure JasperReports i think its no possible.
There is [Web Service Data Source](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/web-service-data-source) extension to Jaspersoft (Studio, Server, Library).

I wan't been able to find a way to use it with pure JasperReport Library yet. Installation guides are only for Studio or Server and with them it works fine.

But when you download it from  [this website](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/web-service-data-source/releases) you have also folder "JR" with 3 jars, i guess they should contain classes providing support to JasperReport Library

I think it should be something which implements JRDataSource to pass it 
JasperFillManager.fillReport(String sourceFileName, Map params, JRDataSource dataSource)

Comment: yes thanks for the feedback. I think I will take the JRDataSource path as suggested. What I would have really liked to do is enable the user to configure the report rest parameters (URL, etc...) in Jasper Studio so that I can retrieve them when I create a JRDataSource

Comment: I mean your client already have that extension installed. In Studio or Server you define data adapter and after that you have possibility to use it in your raports.  So url of your client is "http://localhost:8080/api/airports" and he is using GET method to obtain result. Other parameters are defined under

Comment: Other parameters are defined under    <queryString language="WebServiceQuery"> part of jrxml file. 
So in json response he is looking under "_embedded.airportList" for fields "commercialCode" and "classification". I am not sure how to parse jrxml  template it in pure JasperReports Library if you find out please describe it

Comment: OK I will give it a try in the debugger and get back to you :)